# PostGIS Nearest neighbor really slow

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, knn

I'm trying to set a link between two tables (db1 and db2) with a nearest neighbor approach and some condition checking.

```
SELECT id, label_shop, linked_rows.*
FROM shopitem.shopitem_database shop
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
    FROM mv_db2 db2
    WHERE (name_1 ~* ('\y' || label_brand || '\y')
           OR name_2 ~* ('\y' || label_brand || '\y')
           OR name_3 ~* ('\y' || label_brand || '\y')
           OR name_4 ~* ('\y' || label_brand || '\y')
           OR name_5 ~* ('\y' || label_brand || '\y')
           OR name_6 ~* ('\y' || label_brand || '\y'))
    AND ST_DWithin(shop.geom, db2.geom, 0.01)
    ORDER BY shop.geom <-> db2.geom asc
    LIMIT 1) linked_rows
on 1=1
WHERE label_brand = 'LABEL 1'
```

I can't figure out what exactly is the bottleneck, I've vacuumed + analyzed both tables.
I've built a btree index for the name_x and a gist index on shop.geom and db2.geom.

`AND ST_DWithin(shop.geom, db2.geom, 0.01)` is only meant to be a safeguard in case of the conditions are never met.
I would want to increase safeguard range but if I do i'll increase rows lookup and it will be even worse.
For your information, this query returns me in ~3min.

Explain analyze: https://explain.depesz.com/s/OyuT

Comment: try removing the st_within and filter the results by distance at the end of the query

Comment: thanks for your answer. Indeed, it fasten up the query but it changes the behavior of my request. I'll have joined rows that I don't want to be. I said that the distance check was a safeguard but it's also a way to not join rows that are too far away. It would imply cleaning my table with a second request. If I have no better solution, i'll definitely apply this.

Answer (score 4):

**Issues:**

- A *(K) Nearest Neighbor* search over (supporting) index structures is fast because the traversal of said index returns inherently sorted hits - the operation gathers the row references into a `K` sized bucket, and the actual rows get fetched on return.

  The crucial part is that this accesses the actual rows only *after* it gathered their references from the index; to apply additional filter conditions on columns (not included in the index) in that row, the DB engine needs to fetch those values *during traversal* of the index, which has a *significant* overhead.
  In fact, the index-to-data access has such a high performance loss that the planner will **deny** an index usage for all but the most basic filter conditions, or if it determines that the expected post-filter result set is large enough that a sequential scan over the data is faster (more than a few percent of the row count).
- Except for cases where filter conditions on multiple columns can be resolved set-theoretically (`UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` on result sets that are chained by logical operators `AND` or `OR`), PostgreSQL will only ever use a *single index per joined relation* - so it either uses the indexes on the text column(s - if possible), **or** the spatial index on `geom` (for which it *may* be able to boost the sorting).
- Except for plain *equality*, `BTREE` indexes on text columns will ever only kick in for *left-anchored* search patterns - *generic text searches* (i.e. regexp searches *over the whole string*) are not supported; there are specific implementations on top of the native `GIN` and `GIST` indexes available

**Options:**

- The most effective strategy is to somehow minimize the complexity (and column involvement) of the pattern matching:

  - try to normalize the `name_x` columns into a single, reduced column to compare against; if possible, try to find a way to utilize simple `LIKE` check conditions
  - alternatively, create a `label_brand:name_x` look-up relation, having an `INTEGER` *Primary Key*, to be able to only filter for `INTEGER` values in your *(K)NN* query
- You can try concatenating your `name_x` columns and make a simple `LIKE` lookup, i.e. `WHERE name_a || name_b || name_c LIKE '%' || label_brand || '%'`
- You can see if using a *multi-column* `GIST` index (via `btree_gist` *extension*) is able to boost your query; `geom` should be the first column in the index definiton, then the text columns. Note that this index will be larger, less efficient than a single spatial index for any other query, and it suffers equally from having multiple `name_x` columns, so the first point applies here, too
- add an index on `label_brand` to speed up filtering on `shopitem_database`

Comment: Thank for you detailed answer. I've built a gist index with one more row and I've conserved only one condition with plain equality (on the indexed row). Query returns in 200ms. I can break my request into n requests for my n name, still instead of regex for matching whole word I could use gin index over tsvector ? Do you know something like gist_gin ?

Comment: @Bil11 no - those are fundamentally different index strategies. GIN is also not implemented for PostGIS spatial types, and it doesn't support *Nearest Neighbor* searches. You can use either GIN or GIST for full text search (`tsquery` over `tsvector`s) - however, your use case is likely better solved by normalizing/simplifying your ´names` columns, than with actual full text search over documents; a simple `name_a || name_b || name_c || name_d LIKE '%name%'` would probably work better.